# Using format In python not working (Beginner Question)

Tags: python, coordinates, xyz

I have program that is turning sensor measurements into a .xyz file. 
To do this, it has to write to the file in the form x y z \n
I'm using the following line of code

`f.write('{0:f} 0 {0:f}\n'.format(xpos,zpos))`

`xpos` and `zpos` are both floats

I was expecting the output to the file to be

> xpos 0 zpos

but instead i'm getting

> xpos 0 xpos

I'm not sure why, and I'm not sure any alternative to using format either.

Answer (score 2):

```
f.write('{0:f} 0 {1:f}\n'.format(xpos,zpos))
```

An alternative is:

```
 f.write(str(xpos) +' 0 '+str(zpos)+'\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it that way.

```py
f.write(f"{xpos} 0 {ypos}")
```